# Google Places API: Extracting reviews from single, known company

Tags: php, google-places-api

I am looking for a way to get the current Google reviews of a *specific* company, and use that. I know that I can use the information on https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details, and I have been able to get the reviews of places close to the company that I want.

However, what I'm looking to do, is to get the latest reviews from a set, specific company (my own) through the API. I cannot seem to find how I can identify specifically my own company. On the API page on Google, it says that you must use the "reference" parameter. However, I've been unable to figure out how I can find that parameter for my own business.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your company has a Place in Google Maps, do a [search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and use the returned reference now and in the future.  As far as I know, references do not expire.